# vb.net reporting hide tablix with expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a report which have a tablix within a tablix as shown here:

[image]

The second Tablix I need to hide when the rows are less than 13.
I have the following expression in the group details property hidden :

=IIf(RunningValue(Fields!blokno.Value, CountDistinct, "Tablix5") >= 13, False, True)

However, it does not work. The header row still shows. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's benefit. I have also added a Visibility expression for the tablix, apart from the group details hidden expression. This worked. The expression I used 
is : =IIf(CountDistinct(Fields!blokno.Value) >= 13, False, True)